# How to edit a unix executable file

Tags: java, file, unix, jar, executable

I have a homework in which my professor gave us a java program inside a directory named "example" and asked us to copy that directory to a new directory named "fixedExample." Then he asked us to rename bin/runExample to bin/runFixedExample and edit that file so that it refers to FixedExample.jar. After that we can start working on the code to fix it.

My problem is that I can't find a way to modify bin/fixedExample since it is a run file.

Comment: It's probably not a "run file" but a script. Have you tried opening it in an editor?

Comment: Whether you can or how you do edit a file has nothing to do with whether it is executable.  It *does* depend on the format of the file, of course, but that's a separate question.  Anyway, although you didn't specify exactly what kind of file you are asked to edit, it seems likely to be a shell script.  In that case, you can edit it with the text editor of your choice.

Comment: yes I tried but it does not open. it is a "Unix Executable File"

Comment: What editor did you try?  And who says the file is a "UNIX Executable File"?  Is that what the `file` command says about it?

Comment: I think you are right. I used a different editor and I was able to edit the file. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem correctly, you simply need to rename something within the bin folder. You could simply use the mv command for it.

```
sudo mv /bin/runExample /bin/runFixedExample
```

Then edit it by using whatever text editor, such as nano or vim.

And put in:

```
java -jar pathToFixedExample.jar
```